# Using different Internet connections with different applications

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-connection, utorrent

I have both a WiFi connection and a Internet enabled dongle. What I hope to do is to use the WiFi for µTorrent and my dongle for my chrome browser. Is this possible?

I found some articles about using multiple Internet connections simultaneously, but I don't believe that those answered my need as they seemed to deal with load-balancing instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use utorrent in a while, but I do believe you can bind utorrent to a specific interface by setting `net.outgoing_ip` in advanced settings to your wifi ip address.

As for chrome, you could set up a local proxy bound to that specific interface - offhand, I know that [dispatch proxy](https://github.com/Morhaus/dispatch-proxy) would do this but there may be better options. While it may be a 'load balancer', it also lets you tell it explicitly which IP addresses to bind to.

Comment: I tried setting `net.outgoing_ip`, but apparently there is a known issue where Win overrides this setting. Will keep trying. Thanks!